# How to set DataContext on multiple Windows/Pages/Controls?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datacontext

I have a question about how WPF MVVM works and have working code but not sure why it's working. Most of the tutorials online seem to give examples using a single Window so I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly with multiple windows/pages/usercontrols.

If I have a class named `ViewModel` and I set the `DataContext` in `MainWindow` using the code below, then I've set the `DataContext` of the `MainWindow` only.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class MainWindow

{
    Private ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel();

    public MainWindow()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       this.DataContext = this.viewModel;
    }

}
```

If I then create a new usercontrol and then bind a DataGrid without specifying a path to the viewModel, why does the code below work when I haven't set the `DataContext` of the usercontrol?

Is this how WPF works or should I also be setting the DataContext in the usercontrol? What is the correct method to do this?

**MainSignals.xaml:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="ProjectXYZ.Content.MainSignals"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:core="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ProjectXYZ.Content"
             xmlns:mui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" >
    <Grid>
        <DockPanel>
            <DataGrid Name="DG1" ItemsSource="{Binding ReceivedSignals}"  >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <mui:DataGridTextColumn Header="SignalID"  Binding="{Binding signalID}"/>
            <mui:DataGridTextColumn Header="SignalType"  Binding="{Binding signalType}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**ViewModel.cs:**

```
private ObservableCollection<MainWindow.SignalVar> _receivedSignals;

Public ViewModel()
{
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


// Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}

public ObservableCollection<MainWindow.SignalVar> ReceivedSignals
{
    get { return _receivedSignals; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _receivedSignals)
        {
            _receivedSignals = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ReceivedSignals");
        }
    }
}
```

**UserControl.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class MainSignals : UserControl
{

    public MainSignals()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //this.DataContext = new ViewModel();  //WORKS WITHOUT THIS??
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the fact that child control inherit the `DataContext` of their parent if their `DataContext` is not set explicitly. This is true for some of the `DependancyProperties` e.g if you set the Foreground of parent control all the child control inherit the same value of Foreground property.

In your case, as you have not set the `DataContext` explicitly for the child UserControl, it will take the DataContext of its parent, which is your Window here.